# Inject a bean from another application context?

Tags: java, spring, jms, rmi, distributed

Is it possible to inject a bean from a web application that deploy in another server!

I declare a scenario to myself, I have two web application that use spring framework and deploy separately in different application servers (one is TOMCAT and another one is WEBLOGIC),the first application has ServiceA and the second one has ServiceB, now I want to inject ServiceB in ServieA?

I try to do this with RMI once an another one with JMS, now I am wondering that:

Is it possible with another thing?
Is there any active project about this scenario exist?
How can share application context in spring framework, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, called web services

Comment: Or you can use REST (with Spring MVC).

Answer (score 1):

Bean is just an object in JVM. You certainly cannot use an object from one JVM in another JVM straightforward.

But you can do 2 things:

1. Use proxies - some objects that will have the same interface but invoke somehow to the proper server as implementation.
2. Use service-oriented architecture (SOA). Each server should have some limited set of beans that are responsible for their functionality. And all beans can interact with each other.
   Maybe OSGI is suitable for this.

Comment: what is the case if the two apps run on the same tier? they run in the same JVM, doesn't they?

Answer (score 0):

Web services, JAX-RS is the simplest. But JAX-WS provides you with the tools to automatically generate the client code.